# Disable logging for one docker container v2.3.3

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running docker compose version 2.3.3, I am attempting to disable logging for a single container. Ive tried using:

```
logging:
    driver: none
```

However logs for my application still show up within the terminal. I have also tried the --attach option but that doesnt seem available.

Answer (score 0):

setting the logging driver changes where docker persists captured logs to, and consequently the availability of logs to `docker logs` / `docker compose logs` commands.
Its not going to inhibit stdout/err in the container itself. If you need to quash that, given you have a net core app, you need to edit the LogLevel in appsettings.json to be less verbose. "Warning", or "Error" perhaps.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running the container in detached mode? I.e. - `docker compose up -d` or `docker compose up --detach`.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. When running in detached mode will it still run any logs in the background. The problem is the logging is taking alot of memory on machine when running docker compose

Comment: A couple of things. 
1. What do you mean by "run any logs"? If the code has logging steps the output will be created, it's just a matter of where they are cast to. In theory you could pipe all of them to something like `/dev/null` if you truly don't want them to exist after they are created.
2. What memory is being overutilised? Disk or RAM?

Comment: 1. Logging as in application code logs coming from .NET Core 2.RAM